Dropzone - Cannot Get Preview from Existing Image on Server to Show
I have this working example of Dropzone, but I am trying to add a previously uploaded image that I have on my server. The part where "init" starts is where the issue is.  It does not like the "thisDropzone.displayExistingFile".  I think that i need to use dropzone.options, but I cannot seem to bind that to a DIV.
Any thoughts?  I could not find any full working examples on their gitlab or website, which I thought was weird so any help would be appreciated!  thank you.
$("div#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone({
    url: "/data/upload.php",
    maxFilesize: 1,
    thumbnailHeight: 100,
    thumbnailWidth: 100,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    success: function (file, response) {
        var imgName = response;
        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
        console.log("Successfully uploaded :" + imgName);
    },
    error: function (file, response) {
        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
    },
    init: function() {
        thisDropzone = this;
    
        var mockFile = { name: "Filename 2", size: 12345 };
        thisDropzone.displayExistingFile(mockFile, "https://www.link-to-image/myimage.jpg");
        alert("test")
    }
});

I have been playing around with this for hours.  It has something to do with the way I am calling the init, I just cannot find an example of hour to do this and bind it to my DIV.
